# Move firebase records

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a Firebase database like this:

Sales

```
+ Key
    · customer: 
    · number:
    + Products
            + Key
                · productName: 
                · productPrice: 
                · productId:
            + Key
                · productName: 
                · productPrice: 
                · productId:
```

I would like to organised data in a different way. Like this:

Sales

```
+ Key:
    · customer: 
    · number:
    + Products
            + Key: true
            + Key: true
```

Products

```
+ Key
    · productName: 
    · productPrice: 
    · productId:
    · salesKey: salesKey
```

I am using angular in my Web App. I can create a function that will copy each product information and push it in "Products"  then take the key and set it with true value inside Sales/Products. 
I have around 6,000 records. Can Firebase handle this query? 
Is this good practice when changing data structure?

Answer (score 1):

For 6K records, loading them all in one go and changing them sounds fine to me.

If the data grows beyond a few tens of thousands of items you might want to consider walking over the records in batches. But with 6000 reasonably sized records, you should be fine.

An alternative would be to download the data from the Firebase Console, modify it locally and then re-import it in the Firebase Console.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I would go ahead and try the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.on(value)` to retrieve all your nodes in a single read call, and then use the [data fan-out method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#update_specific_fields) to make a single update write call.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will review that part of the documentation.